# binomial distibution in r, cannot replicate correct answer

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm given a problem:

An event occurs with probability 0.7. Over the course of 10,000 events the event occurred only 55 times.

Verbatim question

> What is the probability that you would observe at most that many events, if the probability of each click was 0.7%?

The solution provided is 0.0372.

In r I typed `pbinom(55, 10000, 0.7)` which returns just 0.

How can I arrive at 0.0372?

Comment: 0.7% = 0.007... If probability of observing something is 70%, then observing it only 55 times in 10000 trials sounds pretty impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R...

```
p = 0.7/100
N = 10000
pbinom(55,N,p)
>[1] 0.03720226
```

Looks like you have an error in your call to `pbinom`.  If there is a 0.7% chance of an event occuring, then `p=0.7/100` not `p = 0.7`.